# Git merge script

Tags: shell, git

The branches I need to merge are called test and test-passed. Merging will always be fast-forward, from test to test-passed as commits to test-passed are only done automatically from test. This is currently working, just wondering if the approach is correct. The script is executed by Hudson, once all testing is complete.

```
git status
git reset --hard
git pull origin test
git checkout origin/test
git pull origin test-passed
git checkout origin/test-passed
git merge origin/test
git push origin HEAD:test-passed
```

One specific question I have, is if I need to create local branches as well (-b) or is that not required?

Output from above:

> ```
> + git status
> HEAD detached from origin/test-passed
> nothing to commit, working directory clean
> + git reset --hard
> HEAD is now at 16a2d8d updated version
> + git pull origin test
> From ssh://github.com/myrepo.git
>  * branch            test       -> FETCH_HEAD
> Already up-to-date.
> + git checkout origin/test
> HEAD is now at 16a2d8d... updated version
> + git pull origin test-passed
> From ssh://github.com/myrepo.git
>  * branch            test-passed -> FETCH_HEAD
> Already up-to-date.
> + git checkout origin/test-passed
> Previous HEAD position was 16a2d8d... updated version
> HEAD is now at 2aa260d... Merge branch 'dev-integration' into test
> + git merge origin/test
> Updating 2aa260d..16a2d8d
> Fast-forward
>  app/application.properties                                     | 8 ++++----           
>  4 files changed, 14 insertions(+), 5 deletions(-)
> + git push origin HEAD:test-passed
> To ssh://git@github.com/myrepo.git
>    2aa260d..16a2d8d  HEAD -> test-passed
> ```

Comment: What branch are you on when you run the script?

Comment: Using the hudson git plugin, I checkout test, updated with output

Comment: So you want to make `origin/test-passed` identical to `origin/test`? Why bother having a local `test-passed` branch at all?

Comment: When test-passed is updated (meaning test has a stable build) a different service picks up code and deploys.

Comment: Four argument versions of `fetch` and `pull` don't update local branch refs (you can see that in your output `test -> FETCH_HEAD`. What are you expecting those lines are doing for you? Why are you checking out `origin/test` before checking out `origin/test-passed`? Checking out remote refs doesn't leave you on a local branch (you might already realize this because your push line uses `HEAD` to make the push work) but I figured it was worth mentioning specifically just to be sure. If your merge is always a fast-forward then use `--ff-only` on the merge to have git ensure that too.

Comment: @200_success I don't believe there are any local refs here at all actually.

Answer (score 2):

### use variables

Pulling common elements into variables will make those things easier to follow and change later.

```
BRANCH_TEST="test"
BRANCH_PASSED="test-passed"

git status
git reset --hard
git pull origin $BRANCH_TEST
git checkout origin/$BRANCH_TEST
git pull origin $BRANCH_PASSED
git checkout origin/$BRANCH_PASSED
git merge origin/$BRANCH_TEST
git push origin HEAD:$BRANCH_PASSED
```

### error checking

Is there any chance one of the steps will fail?  You could check the return value of each step or just [`set -e`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4382179/2002471) to get bash to exit on any command having an error.

There is also [bash strict mode](http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/) which builds on `set -e` with some other things to make coding in the shell less surprising.

### documentation

It would be a good idea to explain what the intent of the code is.

### shebang

Presumably this is a bash script.  It would be good to make it clear by putting

```
#!/bin/bash
```

as the first line.